# Docker login on ECR fails with 400 Bad Request on Powershell from Jenkins

Tags: docker, powershell, jenkins, kubernetes

I've problem running `docker login` against AWS ECR with Powershell. 
More specifically I'm running it from a Jenkins pipeline on Windows container (inside a K8S cluster) using the `powershell` step as follow

```
powershell "aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ****.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
```

but it fails with following error:

```
09:24:32  At C:\Jenkins\agent\workspace\test\awsIamRole-Test@tmp\durable-e2ffd0da\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
09:24:32  + & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
09:24:32  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
09:24:32      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error response ...400 Bad Request    :String) [], RemoteException
09:24:32      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

The strange behavior is that if I run the command **manually** on the container (both on my local machine and on the cluster) everything works fine and the login is successful. Below there's the container's Dockerfile.

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809

SHELL ["powershell"] 

RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
RUN choco install jq docker -y 
RUN choco install awscli --version=2.1.15 -y
```

Since the container runs on an EC2 instance and I need to run Docker inside the container, I bind to Docker socket of underlying EC2 machine when launching the container on K8S, as shown below (it works since `docker ps` from the pipeline show the correct results).

```
  - image: "****.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/jenkins-container-templates/docker-awscli2-windows:latest"
    name: "docker-awscli2-windows"
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "\\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine"
      name: "docker-pipe"
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: "\\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine"
    name: "docker-pipe"
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Running into the same issue using Powershell, I use a different CLI to interact as it does not seem to play nice with Powershell. Could it be that you can try and run it as an Administrator?

Comment: There seems to be an issue when running the command in PowerShell, using git bash terminal works

Comment: @PeetvdWesthuizen you bumped into this running directly on PowerShell? For me works fine running it directly, it's just a problem running it from Jenkins.

Comment: @Yidir thanks but unfortunately I cannot use it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

#### Problem cause

It seems that problem is related to how pipes are managed when running powershell on Jenkins and for some reason (that I haven't figured out yet), a new line is added before the token, so that instead of

```
token
```

the second part of the command get as input

```
token
```

and it probably process it like there is no input at all and the `--password-stdin` flag make it fail with `BadRequest` status.

#### Workaround

Since I was unable to remove this new line, I used as workaround

```
powershell 'docker login --username AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 ) ****.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Comment: In my case, the weird thing about this is that is started happening randomly today for the first time. Can't imagin what has changed that made it do this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I had to disable Tag immutability in my ECR repo to get this working !

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below command in pwsh:

`aws ecr get-login-password --profile $PROFILE --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com`

Login Succeeded

Answer (score 0):

*cli-auto-prompt* is "on"?

```
aws ecr get-login-password --profile $PROFILE --region $AWS_REGION --no-cli-auto-prompt | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com
```